# Search in List of X509CRL's

Tags: java, security, certificate, x509certificate

I have a list of X509 CRL's. I need to identify some of them somehow. Right now I do it using issuer:

```
for(var crl: List<X509CRL> crls){
 String issuer = c.getIssuerX500Principal().getName();
 if(issuer.contains("searchString"))
  result.add(crl);
}
```

But there's gotta be a better way to do that using knowledge of CRL file format, maybe with comparing public keys or something like that, but I don't know much about X509CRL's. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the public key of each certificate, you can utilize the `verify(PublicKey key)` method to verify that the CRL was signed using the private key that corresponds to the given public key.

If the key is incorrect, it should throw an `InvalidKeyException`, so surround it with a try-catch block, like this:

```java
try {
    crl.verify(<public_key>)
} catch(InvalidKeyException e) {
    // handle exception
}
```

### See also:

- [Class X509CRL - verify](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/cert/X509CRL.html#verify(java.security.PublicKey))

Comment: But the return type is void, what will happend if it's not the needed certificate, how would I know that?

Comment: I've edited my answer with a few more details :)

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the solution from @Pexers would be using either the X509 Certificate or a list of X509 Certificate serial numbers and calling either of these in a loop;

`X509CRLEntry getRevokedCertificate(BigInteger serialNumber)`

or

`X509CRLEntry getRevokedCertificate(X509Certificate certificate)`

The result will be the X509CRLEntry if they are in the CRL or null if they are not.

Processing a large number of Certificates and/or CRLs in this way would reduce the need to catch and handle an exception for each one.